# Do parallel processing for files in same folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, video-processing

I Have doubts about parallel processing, I extracted frames from the video it will store into the H5 file now I want to do this in parallel processing,

what I am tried :

I tried to generate a file for all videos and its features like features change point and all other things

expected :

Generate h5 file via parallel processing

```
import os
from networks.CNN import ResNet
from utils.KTS.cpd_auto import cpd_auto
from tqdm import tqdm
import math
import cv2
import numpy as np
import h5py
import numpy as np

class Generate_Dataset:
    def __init__(self, video_path, save_path):
        self.resnet = ResNet()
        self.dataset = {}
        self.video_list = []
        self.video_path = ''
        self.h5_file = h5py.File(save_path, 'w')

        self._set_video_list(video_path)

    def _set_video_list(self, video_path):
        # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        if os.path.isdir(video_path):
            self.video_path = video_path
            fileExt = r".mp4",".avi"
            self.video_list = [_ for _ in os.listdir(video_path) if _.endswith(fileExt)]
            self.video_list.sort()
        else:
            self.video_path = ''
            
            self.video_list.append(video_path)

        for idx, file_name in enumerate(self.video_list):
            self.dataset['video_{}'.format(idx+1)] = {}
            self.h5_file.create_group('video_{}'.format(idx+1))


    def _extract_feature(self, frame):
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (224, 224))
        res_pool5 = self.resnet(frame)
        frame_feat = res_pool5.cpu().data.numpy().flatten()

        return frame_feat

    def _get_change_points(self, video_feat, n_frame, fps):
        n = n_frame / fps
        m = int(math.ceil(n/2.0))
        K = np.dot(video_feat, video_feat.T)
        change_points, _ = cpd_auto(K, m, 1)
        change_points = np.concatenate(([0], change_points, [n_frame-1]))

        temp_change_points = []
        for idx in range(len(change_points)-1):
            segment = [change_points[idx], change_points[idx+1]-1]
            if idx == len(change_points)-2:
                segment = [change_points[idx], change_points[idx+1]]

            temp_change_points.append(segment)
        change_points = np.array(list(temp_change_points))

        # temp_n_frame_per_seg = []
        # for change_points_idx in range(len(change_points)):
        #     n_frame = change_points[change_points_idx][1] - change_points[change_points_idx][0]
        #     temp_n_frame_per_seg.append(n_frame)
        # n_frame_per_seg = np.array(list(temp_n_frame_per_seg))
        # print(change_points)
        arr = change_points
        list1 = arr.tolist()
        list2 = list1[-1].pop(1) #pop [-1]value 
        print(list2)
        print(list1)
        
        print("****************") # [-1][-1] value find and divided by 15
       
        cps_m = math.floor(arr[-1][1]/15)
        list1[-1].append(cps_m)             #append to list 
        print(list1)
        
        print("****************") #list to nd array convertion
        
        arr = np.asarray(list1)
        print(arr)

        arrmul = arr * 15
        print(arrmul)

        print("****************")   
        # print(type(change_points))
        # print(n_frame_per_seg)
        # print(type(n_frame_per_seg))
        median_frame = []
        for x in arrmul:
          print(x)
          med = np.mean(x)
          print(med)
          int_array = med.astype(int)
          median_frame.append(int_array)
        print(median_frame)
        #   print(type(int_array))
        return arrmul

    # TODO : save dataset
    def _save_dataset(self):
        pass

    def generate_dataset(self):
        print('[INFO] CNN processing')
        for video_idx, video_filename in enumerate(self.video_list):
            video_path = video_filename
            if os.path.isdir(self.video_path):
                video_path = os.path.join(self.video_path, video_filename)
            video_basename = os.path.basename(video_path).split('.')[0]
            video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
            fps = video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
            n_frames = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
            frame_list = []
            picks = []
            video_feat = None
            video_feat_for_train = None
            for frame_idx in tqdm(range(n_frames-1)):
                success, frame = video_capture.read()
                if frame_idx % 15 == 0:

                    if success:

                        frame_feat = self._extract_feature(frame)                    
                        picks.append(frame_idx)

                        if video_feat_for_train is None:
                            video_feat_for_train = frame_feat
                        else:
                            video_feat_for_train = np.vstack((video_feat_for_train, frame_feat))
                        if video_feat is None:
                            video_feat = frame_feat
                        else:
                            video_feat = np.vstack((video_feat, frame_feat))
                    else:
                        break
            video_capture.release()
            arrmul = self._get_change_points(video_feat, n_frames, fps)
            self.h5_file['video_{}'.format(video_idx+1)]['features'] = list(video_feat_for_train)
            self.h5_file['video_{}'.format(video_idx+1)]['picks'] = np.array(list(picks))
            self.h5_file['video_{}'.format(video_idx+1)]['n_frames'] = n_frames
            self.h5_file['video_{}'.format(video_idx+1)]['fps'] = fps
            self.h5_file['video_{}'.format(video_idx + 1)]['video_name'] = video_filename.split('.')[0]
            self.h5_file['video_{}'.format(video_idx+1)]['change_points'] = arrmul
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
'''
first import the following, here Parallel will parallelize the processing and
delayed is the wraper.
'''
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

'''
Now we create a new function and copy paste everything that was previously
inside the for loop and pass `video_idx and video_filename` as arguments.
'''

def _generator(self, video_idx, video_filename):
    video_path = video_filename
            if os.path.isdir(self.video_path):
                video_path = os.path.join(self.video_path, video_filename)
            video_basename = os.path.basename(video_path).split('.')[0]
            video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
            fps = video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
            n_frames = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
            frame_list = []
            picks = []
            video_feat = None
            video_feat_for_train = None
            for frame_idx in tqdm(range(n_frames-1)):
                success, frame = video_capture.read()
                if frame_idx % 15 == 0:

                    if success:

                        frame_feat = self._extract_feature(frame)                    
                        picks.append(frame_idx)

                        if video_feat_for_train is None:
                            video_feat_for_train = frame_feat
                        else:
                            video_feat_for_train = np.vstack((video_feat_for_train, frame_feat))
                        if video_feat is None:
                            video_feat = frame_feat
                        else:
                            video_feat = np.vstack((video_feat, frame_feat))
                    else:
                        break
            video_capture.release()
            arrmul = self._get_change_points(video_feat, n_frames, fps)
            self.h5_file['video_{}'.format(video_idx+1)]['features'] = list(video_feat_for_train)
            self.h5_file['video_{}'.format(video_idx+1)]['picks'] = np.array(list(picks))
            self.h5_file['video_{}'.format(video_idx+1)]['n_frames'] = n_frames
            self.h5_file['video_{}'.format(video_idx+1)]['fps'] = fps
            self.h5_file['video_{}'.format(video_idx + 1)]['video_name'] = video_filename.split('.')[0]
            self.h5_file['video_{}'.format(video_idx+1)]['change_points'] = arrmul

'''
Finally we update our current function using Parallel and delayed.
'''

def generate_dataset(self):
    print('[INFO] CNN processing')
    Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(self._generator)(video_idx, video_filename) for video_idx, video_filename in enumerate(self.video_list))
```

Comment: How to pass `def _generator(self, video_idx, video_filename):` in `create_data.py`  `gen = Generate_Dataset(args.input, args.output)
    gen._generator()`

Comment: https://github.com/Chuttyboy/H5_Generation/blob/main/create_data.py how to pass functions here